# C# - How to print aspect ratio / full page

Tags: c#

I am printing the CHART control on button click:

```
chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);

PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.PrintPage += (s, ev) =>
{
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, Point.Empty); // adjust this to put the image elsewhere
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
};
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

doc.Print();
```

How do I force it to print the control so that it fits to the size of the page (preserving the aspect ratio)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least two different ways to do it, both *include scaling the image to be printed to fit the page size* of the selected printer:

1) using [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) facilities (haven't tested it myself, lifted from this [post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/152545-resizing-and-printing-an-image/)):

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Image i = pictureBox1.Image;

        float newWidth = i.Width * 100 / i.HorizontalResolution;
        float newHeight = i.Height * 100 / i.VerticalResolution;

        float widthFactor = newWidth / e.MarginBounds.Width;
        float heightFactor = newHeight / e.MarginBounds.Height;

        if(widthFactor>1 | heightFactor > 1)
        {
            if(widthFactor > heightFactor)
            {
                newWidth = newWidth / widthFactor;
                newHeight = newHeight / widthFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = newWidth / heightFactor;
                newHeight = newHeight / heightFactor;
            }
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
    }
}
```

2) [P/Invoke'ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) calls from the GDI and flat GDI (this is much more complex but faster and you can pass a plain byte array of a bitmap file (read file as byte[]), provide an email to me if need this code):

```
  private static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);
  private static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);
  private static extern int SetJob(IntPtr hPrinter, int JobId, int Level, ref byte pJob, int Command_Renamed);
  private static extern int GdiplusStartup(out IntPtr token, ref StartupInput input, out StartupOutput output);
  private static extern int GdiplusShutdown(IntPtr token);
  internal static extern int GdipLoadImageFromStream([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]IStream stream, out IntPtr image);
  internal static extern int GdipDisposeImage(IntPtr image);
  static internal extern int GdipCreateFromHDC2(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hDevice, out IntPtr graphics);
  static internal extern int GdipDeleteGraphics(IntPtr graphics);
  static internal extern int GdipReleaseDC(IntPtr graphics, IntPtr hdc);
  internal static extern int GdipGetImageDimension(IntPtr image, out float width, out float height);
  internal static extern int GdipGetDpiX(IntPtr graphics, out float dpi);
  internal static extern int GdipGetDpiY(IntPtr graphics, out float dpi);
  static internal extern int GdipDrawImageRectI(IntPtr graphics, IntPtr image, int x, int y, int width, int height);
  private static extern IntPtr CreateDC([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszDriver, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszDevice, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);
  private static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);
  private static extern int StartDoc(IntPtr hdc, DOCINFO lpdi);
  private static extern int EndDoc(IntPtr hdc);
  private static extern int StartPage(IntPtr hdc);
  private static extern int EndPage(IntPtr hdc);
  private static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
```

Comment: @ivo this is nice  but much too complicated, i think there's probably already some kind method print.fullpage() or something like that

Comment: @i am a girl, when I had to do this my research concluded there isn't using .Net or win32 provided apis. I know it's surprising - so many things you can do in .Net but silly things like this require to climb a mountain but I'm pretty sure this is the case. There might be 3rd party libs that can do that but I have no time to research. Also specifically the fact you need to preserve the aspect is a logic problem so my guess is this why Microsoft never  provided easy function to do it because it's a function which deals with image resizing, it can be any size, this case is just one of those cases

Comment: @i am a girl so yes I was also looking for a long time for that printFullPage() function:) But there wasn't one so I had to write my own, provide me email & can send it to you as its too long & proprietary so I don't wanna post it here (also must allow me until tomorrow to strip off some logic customization which is my company's property now). But the first method, I think, is not too bad if it works, is it ? It's very short, try it.

Comment: @ivo thanks so much i appreciate your willingness to help frumrecords GMAIL

Comment: @i am a girl done, check. PS: I don't know why John Saunders edited the title for this question (tags yes) but why the title ? Contact him and tell him you didn't specify GDI+ at all, I think his edit is incorrect. I have no privilege do edit myself

Comment: @ivo s: I agree with your take on the revision and rolled it back.

Comment: @i am a girl no go sorry (invalid again). Try the first option:)

Comment: @ivo are you doing frumrecords@gmail.com?

Comment: Oh hold on a minute, I think my email smtp is blocking attachment. Sorry, I'll send it to you. I didn't even bother opening the failure notice. Let me fix it ...

Comment: It was actually the gmail server blocking zip file so I renamed it to txt. Check if you received it & rename it to zip to extract.

Comment: @i am a girl send it again, I don't receive a failure notice - I think you must receive it, maybe check you smap/junk folders ...

Comment: I added a change to actually do what the OP asked for.  The user wanted to print the ENTIRE page.  Edited the answer to reflect the PageBounds instead of the MarginBounds.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get this working. What's annoying is that the chart control will only draw its contents as the same size that it is sized to on the screen. The only way I found to get around this is to manually resize it. And then, since it may not like being resized when it's on a form, this also involved temporarily removing it from the form.

So with all that, I end up with something like this:

```
Chart ChartBox { get; private set; }

...

var oldParent = ChartBox.Parent;
var oldSize = ChartBox.Size;

ChartBox.Parent = null;
ChartBox.Size = new Size(width, height);

ChartBox.Printing.Print();

ChartBox.Parent = oldParent;
ChartBox.Size = oldSize;
```

Depending on your form, you may need to save and restore other properties of the chart control as well.