# Print form in Windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, desktop-application

Im trying to get a button to print out my current form and have tried all the code I can find on here but it keeps printing blank pages and I cant work out why.

The code I use is as follows

```
Bitmap bitmap;
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Add a Panel control.
Panel panel = new Panel();
this.Controls.Add(panel);

//Create a Bitmap of size same as that of the Form.
Graphics grp = panel.CreateGraphics();
Size formSize = this.ClientSize;
bitmap = new Bitmap(formSize.Width, formSize.Height, grp);
grp = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

//Copy screen area that that the Panel covers.
Point panelLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
grp.CopyFromScreen(panelLocation.X, panelLocation.Y, 0, 0, formSize);

//Show the Print Preview Dialog.
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
//Print the contents.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

This runs from a button (btnPrint) which is on a form (Form2) along with loads of textboxes and graphics)

When clicked it brings up the print preview dialog fine but the page is blank. If I press print it prints a blank page.

Any idea why its not copying the form??

Comment: You hacked this code to death by messing with that Panel.  Your event handler for the printDocument1.PrintPage event handler looks bad.  Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the PrintPage event handler.  With the prediction that it won't break.  Double-click the printDocument1 component in the designer to add the event handler.

Comment: Or better yet: Throw it all away and write a decent printing routine instead of dumping the screen resolution to your printer..

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this I simply used this code straight from an article on here and just couldn't see where it was not working

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer: [How to: Print Preview a Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2k43zdy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern long BitBlt (IntPtr hdcDest, 
int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, 
IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
private Bitmap memoryImage;
private void CaptureScreen()
{
    Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Size s = this.Size;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, 
    mygraphics);
    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(
    memoryImage);
    IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
    IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
    BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width,
    this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 
    13369376);
    mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
    memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object 
sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
}

private void printButton_Click(System.Object sender, 
System.EventArgs e)
{
    CaptureScreen();
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.Show();
}
```

Comment: I used this code before It does run but when the print preview window comes up it says "Document does not contain any pages" Don't Know where i'm going wrong

Comment: @MarkBarr you have uploaded just a text file not the project. So it's not possible for me to run your app on my PC. But i have created a simple project which does the same: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4r8m4weislr4fv/PrintPreviewDemo.zip?dl=0 and Vote my answer as accepted if it helped. :D

Comment: Thank you so much for the project cant quite work out the difference from what I was doing but it does put the form in the print preview however two issues. 1. the image does not shrink the form to fit the page so it only shows half the form and 2. once you print it from the preview and close the preview window if you try to print it again it throws an exception that "you cannot access a disposed object"

Comment: I sorted the second issue by re initializing the component after the button is pressed

Comment: It's quite difficult to guess what's going wrong on your end. If you could upload your whole project, it would be easier for me and others to help you.

Comment: problem is its a sqlite database with sensitive data so I cant upload that ill try a version thats blank

Comment: ok this sort of works "e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, e.MarginBounds);" it shrinks it to a page but doesn't keep aspect ratio any idea how to keep aspect ratio?

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206784/c-sharp-how-to-print-aspect-ratio-full-page

Comment: Thank you The procedure for printing the document worked perfectly with one minor change changing Picturebox1.image to memoryImage Is ther a way of centering the print also the quality of print is not very good compared to printing the form directly

Comment: If you look at the PrintPage event, it includes the printable area as the PrintPageEventArgs.MarginBounds, and you have the size of your image, so centring it is just a case of setting the top left hand corner of the print position to the Width of the print area minus the Width of the image, divided by two for the X, and the Height of the print area minus the Height of the image, divided by two for the Y.

Feed that into the Graphics.DrawImage method, and it will be centred.

Comment: You need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499860/graphics-drawstring-center-in-printdocument-width