# Microsoft Chart size varies on different build server despite defining the fixed height and width

Tags: c#, charts, activereports

I have a problem where I am rendering MS Chart on Pdf on Active Report 6 (Picture control) through memory stream. I have encountered a problem where the size of my chart is varying based on the build server. Not sure which property is causing this issue.
On few build machine the Chart is huge and on few the chart size is reduced.

Any pointer ??

I have a scheduler service built on DotNet framework 3.5 running on my local machine Windows 10.
MS chart version being used - 3.5 Framework
Active Reports - version 6

Where as when actually the service being delivered to QA which is Windows server 2016, the size of chart is being changed .

Below is the code

//*********Chart defining

```
         Chart chart = new Chart();

         chart.Height = 100;

         chart.Width = 250;

         chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("Default"));

         ChartArea chartArea = chart.ChartAreas["Default"];

         chart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = false;

         chart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.X = 10F;

       chart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 95F;

       chart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 54.30373F;

       chart.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Y = 2.500001F;

       chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Default"));

        chart.Legends[0].Enabled = true;

        chart.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

        chart.Legends[0].TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        chart.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Column;

        chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Right;
        chart.Legends[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 5f);
        LegendCellColumn valuey = new LegendCellColumn("", LegendCellColumnType.Text, "#VALY{N0}", ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
        LegendCellColumn symbolCol = new LegendCellColumn("", LegendCellColumnType.SeriesSymbol, "", ContentAlignment.TopLeft);
        chart.Legends[0].CellColumns.Add(symbolCol);
        chart.Legends[0].CellColumns.Add(valuey);
        chart.Legends[0].Position.Auto = false;
        chart.Legends[0].Position = new ElementPosition(55, 55, 35, 45);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            //chart.Titles[0].DockedToChartArea = ;
            chart.Titles.Add(new Title(chartName));
            chart.Titles[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
            chart.Titles[0].Name = chartName;
            chart.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 5.1f);
            chart.Titles[0].Position.Auto = false;
            chart.Titles[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
            chart.Titles[0].Position.Height = 40F;
            chart.Titles[0].Position.Width = 40F;
            chart.Titles[0].Position.X = 60F;
            chart.Titles[0].Position.Y = 30F;
            chart.Titles[0].Text = chartName;
```

Comment: Youll need to had a lot more information, how can we answer this other than saying, "*hrmm, thats odd*" what build servers, what ms build are you using, what are the environmental differences, how are you generating them, have you got pictures of this behavior.  This seems like a question for the company who created the repoting software

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for feedback ! have updated the post with details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to print aspect ratio / full page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206784/c-sharp-how-to-print-aspect-ratio-full-page)